# Define bootstrap col-md-** in ways other than inline

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

Consider the below example

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
   <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 offset-md-4 col-md-4 offset-lg-4 col-lg-4"></div>
   <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 offset-md-4 col-md-4 offset-lg-4 col-lg-4"></div>
   <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 offset-md-4 col-md-4 offset-lg-4 col-lg-4"></div>
   <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 offset-md-4 col-md-4 offset-lg-4 col-lg-4"></div>
   <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 offset-md-4 col-md-4 offset-lg-4 col-lg-4"></div>
   <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 offset-md-4 col-md-4 offset-lg-4 col-lg-4"></div>
   <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 offset-md-4 col-md-4 offset-lg-4 col-lg-4"></div>
   <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 offset-md-4 col-md-4 offset-lg-4 col-lg-4"></div>
   <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 offset-md-4 col-md-4 offset-lg-4 col-lg-4"></div>
   <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 offset-md-4 col-md-4 offset-lg-4 col-lg-4"></div>
   <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 offset-md-4 col-md-4 offset-lg-4 col-lg-4"></div>
   <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 offset-md-4 col-md-4 offset-lg-4 col-lg-4"></div>
   <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 offset-md-4 col-md-4 offset-lg-4 col-lg-4"></div>
   <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 offset-md-4 col-md-4 offset-lg-4 col-lg-4"></div>
   <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 offset-md-4 col-md-4 offset-lg-4 col-lg-4"></div>
   <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 offset-md-4 col-md-4 offset-lg-4 col-lg-4"></div>
   <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 offset-md-4 col-md-4 offset-lg-4 col-lg-4"></div>
   <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 offset-md-4 col-md-4 offset-lg-4 col-lg-4"></div>
   <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 offset-md-4 col-md-4 offset-lg-4 col-lg-4"></div>
   <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 offset-md-4 col-md-4 offset-lg-4 col-lg-4"></div>
   <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 offset-md-4 col-md-4 offset-lg-4 col-lg-4"></div>
   <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 offset-md-4 col-md-4 offset-lg-4 col-lg-4"></div>
   <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 offset-md-4 col-md-4 offset-lg-4 col-lg-4"></div>
   <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 offset-md-4 col-md-4 offset-lg-4 col-lg-4"></div>
   <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 offset-md-4 col-md-4 offset-lg-4 col-lg-4"></div>
   <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 offset-md-4 col-md-4 offset-lg-4 col-lg-4"></div>
   <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 offset-md-4 col-md-4 offset-lg-4 col-lg-4"></div>
   <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 offset-md-4 col-md-4 offset-lg-4 col-lg-4"></div>
   <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 offset-md-4 col-md-4 offset-lg-4 col-lg-4"></div>
   <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 offset-md-4 col-md-4 offset-lg-4 col-lg-4"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Is there a cleaner way to write this, like the below. I don't understand why the bootstrap grid rules have to be specified inline

```
<html>
<head>
   <style>
      .div-alpha
      {
         col-xs:12;
         col-sm:12;
         col-md:4;
         col-lg:4;
         offset-md:4;
         offset-lg:4;
      }
   </style>
</head>
<body>
   <div class="div-alpha"></div>
   <div class="div-alpha"></div>
   <div class="div-alpha"></div>
   <div class="div-alpha"></div>
   <div class="div-alpha"></div>
   <div class="div-alpha"></div>
   <div class="div-alpha"></div>
   <div class="div-alpha"></div>
   <div class="div-alpha"></div>
   <div class="div-alpha"></div>
   <div class="div-alpha"></div>
   <div class="div-alpha"></div>
   <div class="div-alpha"></div>
   <div class="div-alpha"></div>
   <div class="div-alpha"></div>
   <div class="div-alpha"></div>
   <div class="div-alpha"></div>
   <div class="div-alpha"></div>
   <div class="div-alpha"></div>
   <div class="div-alpha"></div>
   <div class="div-alpha"></div>
   <div class="div-alpha"></div>
   <div class="div-alpha"></div>
   <div class="div-alpha"></div>
   <div class="div-alpha"></div>
   <div class="div-alpha"></div>
   <div class="div-alpha"></div>
   <div class="div-alpha"></div>
   <div class="div-alpha"></div>
   <div class="div-alpha"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I'm curious to know why this was down-voted. It has a minimal working example, there is a clear question, and I am not asking for an opinion. I am finding SO is becoming more and more hostile every day. My staff refuses to post questions on it and there is a running joke in our office that SO will "just yell at them"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bootstrap is only a framework; you're free to adapt however you would like. Simply apply the styling that Bootstrap gives to its selectors to your own, and you'll be able to modify to suit.

Bootstrap's `col-` selectors simply apply different styling to elements at given breakpoints.

- `col-xs-` correlates to **`max-width: 768px`** (only affecting phones).
- `.col-sm-` correlates to `min-width: 768px`.
- `.col-md-` correlates to `min-width: 992px`.
- `.col-lg-` correlates to `min-width: 1200px`.

Keep in mind that [**as of Bootstrap 3**](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#overview-mobile), they use [**mobile-first design**](https://www.uxpin.com/studio/blog/a-hands-on-guide-to-mobile-first-design/), so the **order** of the media queries is very important (due to equal [**specificity**](https://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/))! Always start with the **smallest** media query, and work **upwards** to the largest media query (akin to the term 'mobile-first').

You can craft your own media queries to give the same effect as Bootstrap, while cutting down on the required HTML by **combining** various Bootstrap logic classes in your own classes:

```css
/* Purely for visibilty */
.div-alpha {
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.row {
  margin-left: 15px;
  margin-right: 15px;
}

.row::after, .row::before {
  display: table;
  content: " ";
}

.row::after {
    clear: both;  
}

*::after, *::before {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.div-alpha {
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  min-height: 1px;
  padding-right: 15px;
  padding-left: 15px;
}

/* .col-xs- */
@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .div-alpha {
    width:  100%;
  }
}

/* .col-sm- */
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .div-alpha {
    width:  66.66666666%;
  }
}

/* .col-md- */
@media (min-width: 992px) {
  .div-alpha {
    width:  50%;
  }
}

/* .col-lg- */
@media (min-width: 1200px) {
  .div-alpha {
    width:  33.33333333%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="div-alpha"></div>
  <div class="div-alpha"></div>
  <div class="div-alpha"></div>
  <div class="div-alpha"></div>
  <div class="div-alpha"></div>
</div>
```

In the above, I apply the 'core' Bootstrap logic to both `row` and the standalone `.div-alpha`. Then I use media queries to control how it adapts at various different widths (without needing Bootstrap). A JSFiddle of that is **[available here](https://jsfiddle.net/n6g6px69/)**.

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: are you sure `col-xs` is correct? A `min-width` of `768px` means that my PC screen uses it

Comment: Double-checking Bootstrap's [**Grid Options**](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-options), they're using mobile development by *default* with Bootstrap 3. I though it was a bit strange... probably because I've gotten the greater than and less than signs back-to-front in my answer. I'll update it now to correct this :)

Comment: I've corrected my answer to provide the **true** Bootstrap `col-` class logic; my apologies for the confusion!

Answer (score 1):

I don't think we can include classes within classes in CSS, if you are ok with trying javascript to do this, please checkout the below code

```
var classes = "col-xs-12 col-sm-12 offset-md-4 col-md-4 offset-lg-4 col-lg-4"
$('body').children('div').each(function () {
    $(this).addClass(classes);
});
```